# Colored font in sub-menu of a drop-down

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, tinymce-4

The left arrow to be colored **red** which is beside *last name*
[image: The left arrow to be colored]
the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HT8RB/2/)

**Code used in my app**

```
{text:'Student Basic Data', menu:[<% for data in @student_basic_data %>{text:'<%= "◀ #{t(data)}" %>', onclick: function() {editor.insertContent('<i>$%<%= data %>\%</i>');}},<% end %>]},
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
{text:'Student Basic Data', menu:[<% for data in @student_basic_data %>text:'<%= "<span style="color:red;">◀</span> #{t(data)}" %>', onclick: function() {editor.insertContent('<i>$%<%= data %>\%</i>');}},<% end %>]},
```

Comment: sorry, in this case i got no other idea